# Cascading Merge Efficiency

Tags: cascading

There're 2 pipes `pipe1` and `pipe2` to be merged with another pipe `pipe0`.

Is there any efficiency difference between doing

```
pipe0 = new Merge(pipe0, pipe1, pipe2);
```

and

```
pipe0 = new Merge(pipe0, pipe1);
pipe0 = new Merge(pipe0, pipe2);
```

If yes, what's happening behind the scene?

Comment: Asking the question at [Cascading User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cascading-user) might get you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think second one is the most memory efficient one. It is because first one has to merge a large volume of data while the second one will merge smaller dataset multiple times. So first one may be abit fast on the expense of memory.It is upto you to decide.

Have a look at the implementation of Merge class.
https://github.com/cwensel/cascading/blob/30c4b21552ad0db4e3ed3fe8dfed3e702945851a/cascading-core/src/main/java/cascading/pipe/Merge.java